# BigVideo.js show image after video

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm using BigVideo.js (http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) for a background video. I've searched around and can't seem a way to have a poster image after the video has ended. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Ideally, I'd like to have it be transparent if thats at all possible since I already have a background image visible with the backstretch.js jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this works, but since bigvideo.js uses [video.js](https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/api.md) api, you can use `ended` event to check if video play has ended, and do something like:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    _V_("your-video-element").ready(function(){
       this.addEvent("ended", function(){
          //show poster image 
          BV.show(poster_image_url); //BV is bigvideo object
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer made it quite clear for me how to use the videojs events with bigvideo http://stackoverflow.com/a/17591656/436014 which I tested in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/quguwasoge/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

What would the video element be using BigVideo.js? I have a site where clicking on a div plays the background video. So it's not calling a . There is no video element.