# BigVideo.js URL redirect at end of playback

Tags: javascript, html, css, video.js

I have implemented a Background Video on a page using BigVideo which is based off Video.js

When an div is clicked, the video plays in the background. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to redirect to another URL when the video is done playing. This is the code I am using:

Link to play the Video:

```
<a href="vids/gem.mp4" class="home_g"></a>
```

Code to redirect when ended:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_V_("home_g").ready(function(){
    this.addEvent("ended", function(){
        {window.location = "www.google.com"}
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the full test site: [Test Site](http://www.fresh.tc/Gem/index.htm)

After Trying for a few days to get this to work correctly, I've resorted to making a redirect based on the time of the video if anyone else has the same problem. If anyone has the answer to make it work correctly great, if not anyone else could simply do this like I did:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
   redirectTime = "107000";
   redirectURL = "index.htm";
   function timedRedirect() {
   setTimeout("location.href = redirectURL;",redirectTime);
   }
</script>

<a href="vids/gem.mp4" class="home_g" onclick="JavaScript:timedRedirect()"></a>
```

Comment: Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
var BV = new $.BigVideo();

BV.init();


BV.getPlayer().on("ended", function () {
    // your code after video has finished playing
});
```